# Javascript Date object funny behavior with .toLocaleDateString()

Tags: javascript, date, typeerror

Sorry if this is a newbie question...  I have this working correctly:

```
let date = new Date(2021, 0, 12);
dates = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  const dateString = date.toLocaleDateString();
  dates.push(dateString);
}
console.log(dates);
```

All good.  But without the new variable 'dateString', I see a funny behavior I don't quite understand.  Initially I tried to do:

```
let date = new Date(2021, 0, 12);
let dates = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  date = date.toLocaleDateString(); // change same var instead of new var
  dates.push(date);
}
console.log(dates);
```

This throws the following error: TypeError: date.getDate is not a function.  Why should the behavior of the date object change in reverse?

Comment: Once you transform your Date Object into a String and assign it to the `date` variable, it has no `.setDate` or `.getDate` method. It's just a String. Also, in your second example, `dateString` in `undefined` (never declared, never assigned)

Comment: `date = date.toLocaleDateString(); ` overwrites the original object value of the variable to a string value

Comment: I guess my question is:  why is this not a series of operations?  Why doesn't date become a string at the line that calls .toLocaleDateString() instead of changing what the variable was before that line?

Comment: The `toLocaleDateString` method returns a String, but does not alter the Date object it's being called on. That's just how it is

Comment: @blex exactly... so why would adding this line change anything about what the date variable was before this line?  The way I understand this, the date variable should be a Date object up until the line where I assign it the returned string value from .toLocaleDateString().  But once I add that line the typeerror gets thrown the line before saying that date is not an object *before*I call toLocaleDateString().

Comment: The very first iteration (when `i` is `0`) works fine. It's when you enter the second iteration, that the TypeError happens, because you changed the type of `date` before

Comment: @blex of course!! thank you!